# странное поведение, нередактируемый AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

Написал в Android Studio примитивный код с одной активити, все запустилось и  работало.
Решил прописать в манифесте

```
<android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

но ошибся и вместо ...Changes написал ... Change**r**

Теперь возникла проблема. Иcправляю, запускаю, а система обратно возвращает

```
    <android:configChangeR="orientation|screenSize">
```

или удаляю вообще эту строку, но после Shift+F10 коряво написанная строка автоматически опять появляется в манифесте и соответственно

```
Error:(17) No resource identifier found for attribute 'configChanger' in package 'android'
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что это такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: прикрепите скриншот файла, который возвращается из changed в changer сам. У меня есть одна идея, но чтобы подтвердить ее, или опровергнуть, мне нужно знать путь к этому файлу, и его содержимое

Comment: не в том манифесте исправляете. Закройте окно с ним, и выберите манифест в проекте по новой. Обратите внимание на его путь.

Comment: Действительно, я пытался править не тот манифест... debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Вы редактируете `AndroidManifest`, созданный системой. (который назодится в папке `build`)
Файлы в этой папке не должны редактироваться, т. к. они генерируются системой при каждом билде заново. Опечатка же у вас в файле `AndroidManifest`, который лежит в папке с исходниками проекта. Исправьте ошибку в этом файле.